# Nested loops break out unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, loops, nested

I'm trying to create a sudoku game, for those that do not know what it is. You have a 9x9 box that needs to be filled with numbers from 1-9, every number must be unique in its row and column, and also in the 3x3 box it is found. I ended up doing loads of looping within a 2 dimensional array.

But at some point it just stops, with no exceptions whatsoever, just breaks out and nothing happens, and it's not always at the same position, but always goes past half way.

I was expecting a stack overflow exception at least.

Here's my code:

```
public class Engine
{
    public int[,] Create()
    {
        int[,] outer = new int[9, 9];


        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                 outer[i, j] = GetRandom(GetUsed(outer, i, j));
            }
        }

        return outer;

    }

    List<int> GetUsed(int[,] arr, int x, int y)
    {
        List<int> usedNums = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (arr[x, i] != 0 && i != y)
            {
                if(!usedNums.Contains(arr[x, i]))
                    usedNums.Add(arr[x, i]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i, y] != 0 && i != x)
            {
                if (!usedNums.Contains(arr[i, y]))
                    usedNums.Add(arr[i, y]);
            }
        }

        int x2 = 9 - (x + 1);
        int y2 = 9 - (y + 1);

        if (x2 <= 3)
            x2 = 2;
        else if (x2 > 3 && x2 <= 6)
            x2 = 5;
        else x2 = 8;

        if (y2 <= 3)
            y2 = 2;
        else if (y2 > 3 && y2 <= 6)
            y2 = 5;
        else y2 = 8;

        for (int i = x2 - 2; i < x2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = y2 - 2; j < y2; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i, j] != 0 && i != x && j != y)
                {
                    if (!usedNums.Contains(arr[i, j]))
                        usedNums.Add(arr[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }

        return usedNums;
    }

    int GetRandom(List<int> numbers)
    {
        Random r;
        int newNum;
        do
        {
            r = new Random();
            newNum = r.Next(1, 10);
        } while (numbers.Contains(newNum));

        return newNum;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through and seeing where it stops? Also, which function are we talking about? There's half a dozen loops in there..

Comment: I'm stepping through the first loop in the first method "Create()"
It's never the same, sometimes at 4,7 or at 5,3, always at a different position, it seems very random.

Comment: Very...*random* you say?  (I couldn't resist)

Comment: You are on the wrong track; you will never get a successful Sudoku generator using this technique. Read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/SudokuGen.aspx. As the author says "It's nearly impossible to produce a valid Sudoku by randomly plotting numbers and trying to make them fit. Likewise, backtracking with a random placement method is equally ineffective (trust me I've tried both)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *breaking out*, it's getting stuck in an infinite loop.

If I'm reading this right, it looks like you're trying to create a Sudoku board to play on. Trouble is, it's not as simple as you think. As far as I can see, you're just going through it filling it with random unused values; the trouble is, not every such configuration is going to be valid - most of the time your random entries will eventually put you into an unsolvable board configuration.

Then, when you try to select a random value for some square, the inner `GetRandom` function will just loop infinitely trying to pick a number (since `getUsed` will already have all of `1 - 9`, the `do..while` will never exit).

Easy way to see this for yourself: add this at the top of your `GetRandom` function:

```
if (Enumerable.Range(1, 9).All(i => numbers.Contains(i)))
    Console.WriteLine("PROBLEM!");
```

Now, if `numbers` has all of 1 to 9, it'll tell you. (And then still proceed to get stuck in an infinite loop, but that's your problem now ;))

Also, just as a sidenote, it's not good practice to keep making `new Random()` objects like that; better to just have a single instance of `Random`, initialize it in your constructor and then keep using `Random.Next`. At the very least, have `Random r = new Random()` at the top of the function, and then just have `r.Next` inside the loop.

Ok, here's a really simple example of getting into an unsolvable position, just in the first two rows:

```
123|456|789
456|123|X
```

There's no valid number left to put in the position marked `X` - see how that happened?
Filling the grid with random unused numbers isn't the same as filling it with "answers" - think of it this way, if you took a regular sudoku game and tried to *solve* it by just putting any random number that satisfied the rules in each blank square - you'd get stuck pretty soon, right? That's exactly what's happening to your program.

I'd suggest you try writing a sudoku *solver* first, that takes a valid initial board configuration and tries to solve it - then you can move on to trying to make boards yourself.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this way of creating the board will result in unsolvable/multiple solution boards.

Comment: Well at first I am trying to fill it with the answers then I was going to use it and remove some of the values. How can it be unsolvable or with multiple solutions when numbers are unique within their row, column and 3x3 box?

Comment: Undersoon, I get what you mean, I printed the numbers and got that problem you are mentioning.

I started doing this as a challenge for myself really. So I can go on with your suggestion to try a solver first.

Thanks a lot.

one question, since you know that there are 9 occurrences of each number, once in every 3x3,row and col, would that help? As I did not even bother about the amount of times a number occurs.

Comment: While the global number of occurrences _is_ a constraint, it's generally not a _useful_ one - i.e. just knowing that 5 of 9 are on the board doesn't help you in _locating_ where the others should go. Peter Norvig has a great essay on sudoku solvers, check it out: http://norvig.com/sudoku.html

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if in `GetRandom`, your `numbers` list was full of 1-10 already?

I think your program is freezing in the `GetRandom` method because you are telling it to loop infinitely until it finds a number between 1 and 10 that isn't in the list.

You should be telling it to look for **0 to 9**, assuming 0 is "empty", and allowing it to leave if it gets a 0 because only 1-9 matter on the board.  The 0 will be in the list by default it seems, so just ignore it.

```
do
{
   r = new Random();
   newNum = r.Next(0, 9);
} while (numbers.Contains(newNum) && newNum != 0);
```

Give that a shot and see if it works!

Comment: The maxValue shouldn't be included in the range while the minValue is.

I tried already just in case and it filled my array with 0s.

What I don't understand is how could it be going into an infinite loop. The way I see it, it is populating a list of numbers which are already used in the cell's row, column and box so the method does not return it, at the last iteration of the inner loop it should have one number out of 1-9 not used, or am I missing something?

Please note that I am not trying to question your reasoning.

Comment: Have you tried @tzaman's suggestion of putting the check at the top of `GetRandom`?  Your code is not gathering a list of numbers for just 1 cell (which would always be exactly 1 number).  It's gathering a list of numbers used in the row, column and 3x3 enclosing box.  In the first row, there will be no issues.  After that, all bets are off.  The last element of the 2nd row can have an issue, since there are 8 cells before, 1 above, and 1 to the top left.  That's all 10 numbers you are allowing in `Random.Next`.

Comment: I printed the numbers that it managed to create and noticed the problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked the GetRandom for performance

```
static int GetRandom(List<int> usedNums)
{
    List<int> missingNums = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (!usedNums.Contains(i))
            missingNums.Add(i);
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    int rMissingNumIndex = r.Next(0, missingNums.Count - 1);

    return missingNums[rMissingNumIndex];
}
```

and got an exception because usedNums was passed with 10 elements, which means there can be no solution. Try using this method instead and you'll see the the problem.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the problem is with the GetUsed function then or?